# How to convert SET to array in APEX?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have map with key and value and my goal is to get list of 'key'.
I am thinking to get it to the array or List.
Got to the point where I have key values in the SET but haven't figure out
how to convert to the array.

below is my code:

```
Map<String, String> mmm = new Map<String, String>();
mmm.put('one', 'oneee');
mmm.put('two', 'twooo');
mmm.put('three', 'threeee');
mmm.put('four', 'fourff');

//outputs values in the map
system.debug('=======values()==========>' + mmm.values());
//outputs key in the map
system.debug('=======keyset()===========>' + mmm.keyset());

//get keys in the type SET
SET<string> s = mmm.keyset();
//returns 4
system.debug('------------------------------------' + s.size());

s.arrayTo() //this method does not exist :(
```

Comment: For anyone who comes here looking for an answer for `Set`; The question asks about `Set`s, but the code example uses `Map`. The solution mention `keyset()`, but this does not exist for `Set`. If you need to convert a `Set` to a `List`, what I have been doing is using a `Map` instead and adding the value as the key as well, which replicates the `Set` functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `List.addAll` method?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm?SearchType=Stem

If not - you could always manually loop through the set...

Comment: Yes, also after get values by keyset() call, for(String s : keys) works too for iteration. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I like the for(String s : keys) approach best.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use:

Set keys = mmm.keySet();
List keyList = new List(keys);

Answer (score 0):

You should always used generics for type safety.

```
Map<String, String> mmm = new Map<String, String>();
mmm.put('one', 'oneee');
mmm.put('two', 'twooo');
mmm.put('three', 'threeee');
mmm.put('four', 'fourff');

List<String> lstKeys = new List<String>(mmm.keyset());
System.debug('Output : '+lstKeys);
```

As per link : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5447/is-there-a-difference-between-an-array-and-a-list-in-apex .

This solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and simple way to do this would also be:

```
new List<String>(mmm.keySet());
//or
new String[mmm.keySet()];
```

In some code I wrote recently I've got a `Set<String>` and am passing it into a method that takes a `List<String>` with `methodName( new List<String>(setVariable) );` or `methodName(new String[setVariable] );`

---

Yes I know the post is 11+ years old... but it is also what comes up when searching so I put my answer here.